# Allowing user to input nil values with Swift optionals

Tags: ios, swift

I have a user text input and a user image input. I am not sure if the user will input a value or not for any of these, and so I want to make sure these things are optional. Allowing nil text input has been easy enough. I have made my terms optional like so

```
@IBOutlet weak var AskText: UITextView?
```

I am having a very difficult time, however, making terms like this optional:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(((self.UploadHiddenImage!.image))!, 0.5)
```

I am very much being forced to put that "!" in towards the end. It does not accept, for example:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(((self.UploadHiddenImage?.image))?, 0.5)
```

Now after reading around, I am under the impression that "optional binding" and "if let" statements will be my way out. I am having a difficult time understanding them in this context as they relate to a relatively complicated statement like mine.

If someone has a few minutes spare, I would very much appreciate them showing me how to make this kind of statement optional.

**Edit:**

Here are some more details for context

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(((self.UploadHiddenImage!.image))!, 0.5)
    let parseImageFile = PFFile(name:"ask_image.jpeg", data: imageData!)
```

I need this in optional terms in case the user inputs nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

・If you use storyboard, make imageView unoptional like

```
@IBOutlet weak var UploadHiddenImage: UIImageView!
```

・Then unwrap the image of the imageView

```
var parseImageFile: PFFile?
if let image = UploadHiddenImage.image, 
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
    parseImageFile = PFFile(name:"ask_image.jpeg", data: imageData)
}

//use the parseImageFile with if let 
if let parseImageFile = parseImageFile {
} 

//or
parseImageFile?
```

Comment: For my purposes, this is the method that worked.  I used the first paragraph, and then saved to my database as parseImageFile. I didn't end up using the other two statements. Thank you everyone for the conversation and to ZHZ for the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your imageView is optional. The `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` does not accept an optional image input. So you are using the ! to force unwrap the optional and pass a non optional argument to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

However this is not the best approach because if your `self.UploadHiddenImage!.image` is `nil`, your app will crash.

You must use 
`if let myImage = self.UploadHiddenImage!.image as? UIImage { }` 
or even better in swift 2.0 
`guard let myImage = self.UploadHiddenImage!.image as? UIImage else { }` so this code runs only if your `uploadHiddenImage.image` is non-nil.

Comment: `guard` needs a return or break, so it might not be useful in all scenarios.

Comment: Indeed. But it is the most elegant option if his method/function has no point in executing any further when the image is `nil`.

Comment: guard let imageData = self.UploadHiddenImage!.image as? UIImage else { }          gives me error that says "downcast from UIImage? to UIImage only unwraps optionals. Did you mean to use '!'?"

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options depending on your Swift version and how you want your code to look.

If you have Swift 2, the most elegant option will be to use a guard statement.

```
guard let image = self.UploadHiddenImage?.image else {
    return // or handle nil some other way
}

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
let parseImageFile = PFFile(name:"ask_image.jpeg", data: imageData)
```

You can also use an if let statement:

```
if let image = self.UploadHiddenImage?.image {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    let parseImageFile = PFFile(name:"ask_image.jpeg", data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: The if let option does not work. When I go to upload to database later in the script, I'm told that parseImageFile is an unresolved identifier. When I use the guard method, my program is allowed to run, but return is not what I want to do if the input is nil. I just want an empty data cell to enter my database. Instead return is reloading the screen basically. What can I use to send a blank data cell to my table in database when input is nil?

Comment: If you want to use the if let method and have the variables still accessible from outside the scope, you have to do a `var imageData` declaration before the if let scope so it's still available later. As for the guard issue, just change the return line to do what you want, such as, as you said, add an empty cell to your database, then return early.